# Как сделать так, чтобы в инспекторе я сам выбрал, какой метод мне использовать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В скрипте есть два метода:

```
public void PrintHello()
{
    Debug.Log("Привет");
}

public void PrintHowAreYou()
{
    Debug.Log("Как дела?");
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в инспекторе я сам выбрал, какой метод при некоторых обстоятельствах мне использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать так:

```
[SerializedField]
private int Choise = 0;

void Update ()
{
    if (Choise == 0)
        PrintHello();
    else
        PrintHowAreYou();
}

public void PrintHello()
{
    Debug.Log("Привет");
}

public void PrintHowAreYou()
{    
    Debug.Log("Как дела?");    
}
```

И в инспекторе тогда нужно указывать число. Можете там проверку на введенное недопустимое значение обусловить. Но это уже мелочь.

Comment: Такое себе решение, лучше использовать enum, а не обычный int, по крайней мере нужно проверять int на валидность на уровне инспектора, с enum`ом такие махинации не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант с enum. В инспекторе вы выбираете текущее действие из выпадающего списка. При вызове Do() будет происходит соответствующее ему действие.

```
[SerializedField]
ActionType _type;

public void Do()
{
    switch(_type)
    {
            case ActionType.Hello:
                PrintHello();
                break;

            case ActionType.HowAreYou:
                PrintHowAreYou();
                break;
    }
}

void PrintHello()
{
    Debug.Log("Привет");
}

void PrintHowAreYou()
{    
    Debug.Log("Как дела?");    
}

enum ActionType 
{
    Hello,
    HowAreYou
}
```